# scrollToTop not working correctly in ScrollPanel with RadioBox

Tags: wxpython

I'm having a problem with a `wxPython` scrolled panel which contains a radiobox. The scroll bar jumps to the top when trying to select an item from the radiobox when changing focus from another panel. You then need to scroll and click again. A minimal example which reproduces the problem:

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, - 1, "Frame", size=(300, 300))
        self.scrolledPanel = ScrollPanel(self, size=(-1, 200))
        self.panel = PlotTypePanel(self)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox.Add(self.scrolledPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        hbox.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)

class PlotTypePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,**kwargs)
        self.anotherradiobox =  wx.RadioBox(self,label='other',    
                                    style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS,
                                    choices=["some", "other", "box"])

class ScrollPanel(SP.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        SP.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=True, scrollToTop=False)
        choices = [l for l in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"]
        self.fieldradiobox = wx.RadioBox(self,label='letters',    
                                    style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS,
                                    choices=choices)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.fieldradiobox, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scrollToTop=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I click on the other radio panel and back to the scrolled panel, as here,

[image]

it jumps to the top and doesn't select the radio button. I've checked and it seems the `EVT_COMBOBOX` is not triggered by this first click. I've also tried adding `scrollToTop=False` which didn't help. I'm using Python 2.7.3 with wxPython version 3.0.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnChildFocus(self, evt)
If the child window that gets the focus is not fully visible, this handler will try to scroll enough to see it.

Parameters: evt – a ChildFocusEvent event to be processed.

and apparently it works in this case, at least on Linux

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as SP

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, - 1, "Frame", size=(300, 300))
        self.scrolledPanel = ScrollPanel(self, size=(-1, 200))
        self.panel = PlotTypePanel(self)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox.Add(self.scrolledPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        hbox.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)

class PlotTypePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,**kwargs)
        self.anotherradiobox =  wx.RadioBox(self,label='other',
                                    style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS,
                                    choices=["some", "other", "box"])

class ScrollPanel(SP.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        SP.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=True, scrollToTop=False)
        choices = [l for l in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"]
        self.fieldradiobox = wx.RadioBox(self,label='letters',
                                    style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS,
                                    choices=choices)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.fieldradiobox, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHILD_FOCUS, self.on_focus)
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scrollToTop=False)

    def on_focus(self,event):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: It's not an issue but you have `self.SetupScrolling` declared twice.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much @Rolf of Saxony :) Wasted far too long trying to catch switching to panel and radio box events. Any idea where this is documented for wxpython? The double definition is a typo in the minimal example.

Comment: @EdSmith Documented here, although it isn't particularly obvious https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.html#wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.OnChildFocus